# Is subclassing UITabBarController acceptable in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, app-store, uitabbarcontroller

I have a sample program which I was interested in emulating in building my main application, but that sample program does something which I think is probably not permitted. I found some forum posts which suggest Apple will reject an app from the app store if it does this:

```
@interface MainTabBarController : UITabBarController <XXCustomAccessoryDelegate,UIAccelerometerDelegate> {
```

I'm relatively new to iOS development, and I'm not 100% certain about this. I have googled a bit and found some information suggesting "[not to do this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)", but not a firm "you should not do this".

The UI tab bar controller  class that this person has subclassed has `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` connection points, and these are a central part of the application, but it does not override the painting code.  Do I need to rewrite or adapt the code if I want to reuse part of it, before Apple will permit it in the App Store?  Or is it simply overriding to access the view and modify the painting code that Apple does not permit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs have changed between ios5 and ios6.

ios5: " This class is not intended for subclassing."

ios6: "This class is generally used as-is but may be subclassed in iOS 6 and later."

Comment: Okay, I guess the source of my confusion is some dated references to the old doc.s

Comment: @WarrenP It was never "illegal" to subclass `UITabBarController`. I've been doing it since iOS 3.0.

Comment: So then, basically, I've just misunderstood what I've read? Okay.